# SQL hierarchical request CONNECT BY PRIOR no getting the first root

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I  have an INTERSHOP processes table containing all the running jobs and those which ran before, and I want to search and display using hierarchical request.

Here what I've done yet :

```
SELECT LEVEL N, LPAD(' ', 3*LEVEL-3) || P.NAME "HIERARCHY",
    TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(P.STARTDATE, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') STARTTIME,
    TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(P.ENDDATE, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ENDTIME,
    P.HOSTNAME,
    P.SERVERNAME,
    P.STATE
FROM PROCESS P
WHERE FROM_TZ(P.STARTDATE, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris' >= TO_DATE('14/05/2021 08:45', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
    AND FROM_TZ(P.STARTDATE, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris' <= TO_DATE('14/05/2021 10:10', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
CONNECT BY PRIOR P.UUID = P.PARENTUUID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY P.STARTDATE;
```

To get this :

```
| N | HIERARCHY | STARTTIME           | ENDTIME | HOSTNAME | SERVERNAME | STATE |
| - | --------- | ------------------- | ------- | -------- | ---------- | ----- |
| 1 | JOB1      | 14/05/2021 08:41:00 | ...     | ...      | ...        | ...   |
| 1 | JOB2      | 14/05/2021 08:42:00 | ...     | ...      | ..         | ...   |
| 1 | JOB1      | 14/05/2021 08:43:00 | ...     | ...      | ...        | ...   |
| 1 | JOB3      | 14/05/2021 08:44:00 | ...     | ...      | ...        | ...   |
| 2 |  JOB4     | 14/05/2021 08:45:00 | ...     | ...      | ...        | ...   |
| 3 |   JOB5    | 14/05/2021 08:46:00 | ...     | ...      | ...        | ...   |
| 3 |   JOB6    | 14/05/2021 08:47:06 | ...     | ...      | ...        | ...   |
| 1 | JOB1      | 14/05/2021 08:45:00 | ...     | ...      | ...        | ...   |
```

1. I haven't get the real root for hierarchies (those with an UUID but with PARENTUUID = NULL), so it starts at level 2
2. I haven't get all the processes without a PARENTUUID and without a child
3. I have some processes with a PARENTUUID (so child) but not in the tree
4. How can I combine ORDER BY and ORDER SIBLINGS BY to have my list ordered by time ? I think this will be fixed by correcting the 3 previous questions.

Many thanks!

Comment: *but don't want only hierarchies* - what's the difference between a hierarchy of 1 and a hierarchy of more?

Comment: *processes with a PARENTUUID (so child) but at level 1* - sounds like a data modelling error to me, to have some things that are parents according to one rule and other things that are not parents according to the same rule

Comment: Presently I don't find any rows with PARENTUUID = NULL (so no parent, so all alone) but threre is.

Comment: I don't quite understand "i don't find rows.. but there is" - if the rows are in the table, how can you not find them? if the rows are not in the table why do you say "there is"

Comment: Doesn't look too difficult. A basic recursive CTE will do the job. Can you add the sample data for the result you present?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have the data in the table but I don't get the jobs with no PARENTUUID with this request, something wrong with the CONNECT BY PRIOR